# Efficient checking for Subset

Tags: bitarray

Given two bitset objects 'B1' and 'B2' of length 'n' respectively. Whats the efficient way to say whether all the bits that are set in 'B2' are also in 'B1'?

Example:

```
B1 = 110111
B2_bad = 011001
B2_good = 100001
```

So, 'B1' and 'B2_good' is good but not 'B1' and 'B2_bad'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess these two following methods might help. You might need to benchmark them as which is faster.

```
std::bitset<6> B1 (std::string("110111"));
std::bitset<6> B2_bad (std::string("011001"));
std::bitset<6> B2_good (std::string("100001"));
    //////////////One way/////////////////////////
    if ( (~B1 &= (B2_bad)).any()) std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;

    if ( (~B1 &= (B2_good)).any()) std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;

    ///////////////Second way//////////////////
    int i =0;
    for (i = 0; i < B1.size(); ++i) if (B2_bad[i] == 1 && B1[i] == 0) break;
    if (i == B1.size()) std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "No" << std::endl;

    for (i = 0; i < B1.size(); ++i) if (B2_good[i] == 1 && B1[i] == 0) break;
    if (i == B1.size()) std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "No" << std::endl;`
```

Probably, someone more proficient than me can comment on their performance. But my best guess is first method leverages the library functions which should give the best performance , however if most of your queries would have 'Result NO' and B1-B2 will not agree on one of the earlier bits then second method might have better runtime. As, library functions involved have a worst runtime complexity of O(n).